# Is train/test-Split in unsupervised learning of neural network necessary?

Tags: neural-network, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, autoencoder

I am using autoencoder for anomaly detection in warranty data. It is unsupervised. I calculate the reconstruction error by the model and the records with high reconstruction error value is considered as an anomaly. I would like to know, if it is necessary to train/test-split the data.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is still necessary, you are fitting your model on that data and learning it to find a good representation for that sample. Validating whether or not this was actually an anomaly is a lot more difficult then.

Comment: May I draw your attention to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/572346/240550) kindly?